# Need to check to be sure entered URL is https://

Tags: javascript

I need to be sure that someone enters `https://` at the beginning of their URL they enter.

Here is my code and it's not working at all...

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["url"].value;
    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["message"].value;
    var domain = x.split(":");
    var rdomain = domain[0];
    if (y == null || y == "") {
        alert("You Did Not Enter A Message");
        return false;
    }
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("You Did Not Enter A URL");
        return false;
    }
    if ("https".equals(statusCheck)) {
        alert("You Must Use An https:// URL So It's Secure.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have also tried this line in the script:

```
if (rdomain != "https")
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" doesn't work as a problem description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `startsWith`:

```
if (!x.startsWith("https://")) {
    alert("You Must Use An https:// URL So It's Secure.");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex like this:

```
^https:\/\/[^\.]+(\.[^\.\/]+)+(\/[^\/]+)*$
```

You could test it like this:

```
x.match("^https:\/\/[^\.]+(\.[^\.\/]+)+(\/[^\/]+)*$") != null
```

This checks the URL against a few simple rules, and can be used to validate the field too

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TMnFDK/2)